# JQuery Double Click Instead of Single Click

Tags: jquery

I would like to make the on-click overlay link single click instead of double clicking in order for the overlay pop-up to work.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#MainHeadline").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".MainHeadlineOverlay").fadeToggle("fast");
    });
});

$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.MainHeadlineOverlay-wrapper').length){
        $(".MainHeadlineOverlay").hide();
    }
});`
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="Headlines">
<div class="mainheadline">
        <div class="headline">
            <a href="" id="MainHeadline"><img src="boxing.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></a>
        </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="MainHeadlineOverlay" style="display: none;">
<div class="MainHeadlineOverlay-wrapper">
<div class="MainHeadlineOverlay-content">
<a class="closeMain">x</a>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p class="MainHeadlineOverlayAuthor">by Author Date</p>
    <div class="leftoverlay">
        <img src="picture.jpg" height="100%" width="100%;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="rightoverlay">
    </div>
    <div class="bottomoverlay">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Again, I have to double click in order to get the overlay to pop up. I want it to only be a single click.

Comment: maybe you should set up a demo for this or either if you have no idea, share your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have two click handlers, and they contradict each other. Consider these lines:

```
<div class="MainHeadlineOverlay" style="display: none;"> // initially hidden

$(".MainHeadlineOverlay").fadeToggle("fast"); // called first on img click

$(".MainHeadlineOverlay").hide(); // called second on img click
```

On a single click you are effectively always hiding the overlay. When you click again within 200 ms (the [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) "fast" duration), you are able to trigger another `fadeToggle()` to show the overlay from a hidden state. This is the *double click* effect you are referring to.

A simple solution is to exclude `#MainHeadline` from your logic in the `$(document).click()` handler by adding another selector in [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) like so

```
if (!$(event.target).closest('.MainHeadlineOverlay-wrapper, #MainHeadline').length){
```

**Demo:** [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/detece/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thank you Drakes, loved the way you explained it.